# Pandas: Working with missing data in data frame index by time

Tags: python, pandas, date-range

I got the following DataFrame(sample):

```
               date  Value1 Value2
2007-05-25 11:50:00   1       15 
2007-05-25 12:00:00   2       30
2007-05-25 12:10:00   3       25
2007-05-25 12:50:00   2       34
2007-05-25 13:00:00   9       35
2007-05-25 13:10:00   6       10
```

You can see that data from  `2007-05-25 12:20:00` until `2007-05-25 12:40:00` is missing. What I would like to do is a dataframe like this:

```
               date  Value1 Value2
2007-05-25 11:50:00   1       15 
2007-05-25 12:00:00   2       30
2007-05-25 12:10:00   3       25
2007-05-25 12:20:00   NaN     NaN
2007-05-25 12:30:00   NaN     NaN
2007-05-25 12:40:00   NaN     NaN
2007-05-25 12:50:00   2       34
2007-05-25 13:00:00   9       35
2007-05-25 13:10:00   6       10
```

Generally I would like to see which time I had no data. I was thinking something like this:

```
DataRange = pd.date_range(data.index[0],data.index[-1])
data = data.reindex(DataRange, fill_value=nan)
```

But as far as i underastand by testing `date_range` as the function says by its name its date range. So I was wondering if there is a similar with minutes(in my case 10 minutes) or is there is another way to implement that.

Comment: I was afk. Thanks for ur answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample) and pass the rule as '10Min':

```
In [309]:

df.resample('10Min')
Out[309]:
                     Value1  Value2
date                               
2007-05-25 11:50:00       1      15
2007-05-25 12:00:00       2      30
2007-05-25 12:10:00       3      25
2007-05-25 12:20:00     NaN     NaN
2007-05-25 12:30:00     NaN     NaN
2007-05-25 12:40:00     NaN     NaN
2007-05-25 12:50:00       2      34
2007-05-25 13:00:00       9      35
2007-05-25 13:10:00       6      10
```

Some examples can be found [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#up-and-downsampling)